# Review my "delayed for-loop" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have written a small JavaScript class that makes use of `setInterval` to create a delayed loop for iterating an array. I've used this technique in the past but never utilised a library to do so (and as a result it produced quite messy spaghetti code), and so I wrote up this:

```
var DelayedLoop = function() { };

DelayedLoop.forEach = function(collection, delay, callback, completedCallback) {
    var index = 0;
    var timerObject;

    var executor = function() {
        // Stop the delayed loop.
        clearInterval(timerObject);

        // Executes the callback, and gets the returned value to indicate what the next delay will be.
        var newInterval = callback(collection[index++]);

        // If they returned false, quit looping.
        if(typeof(newInterval) == "boolean" && newInterval == false) {
            return;
        }

        // If nothing / non-number is provided, re-use initial delay.
        if(typeof(newInterval) != "number") {
            newInterval = delay;
        } else if(newInterval < 0) { // If a negative number is returned, quit looping.
            return;
        }

        // If there are more elements to iterate, re-set delayed loop. Otherwise, call the "completed" callback.
        if(index < collection.length) {
            timerObject = setInterval(executor, newInterval);
        } else {
            completedCallback();
        }
    };

    // Initial loop setup.
    timerObject = setInterval(function() {
        executor();
    }, delay);
};
```

An example usage can be seen here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myArray = [ "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" ];
    DelayedLoop.forEach(myArray, 1000, function(arrayElement) {
        console.log(arrayElement);
    }, function() {
        console.log("Finished all!");
    });
});
```

How does it look? Are there any browser compatibility issues? Is there any potential flaw I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jeff Mercado touched on many important things, so here are some other things to consider.

1: There's no need to define `DelayedLoop` as a function; you're not using it as one. Instead you can just do a simple object literal:

```
var DelayedLoop = { ... };
```

or simply have a function called `delayedForEach`. If `forEach`is the only function in `DelayedLoop`, there's not much need for the `DelayedLoop` namespace.

2: You could consider copying the `collection` array right away. Otherwise the array your `forEach` function is using can be changed elsewhere, outside the loop. This shouldn't cause any errors with your code, but could lead to confusion.

3: Maybe do some type-checking and throw a TypeError if, for instance, `collection` isn't an array instance, or `callback` isn't a function.

4: No need to both check `newInterval`'s type *and* value when checking if it's false; just use a strict comparison operator: `newInterval === false`. I'd also encourage you to use *only* false as your "stop looping" value; if a callback returns a negative number, just ignore it. This is more in line with how e.g. event handlers or jQuery `each` callbacks work; they can return anything they want, but boolean false - and *only* boolean false - is treated as "stop".

5: No need to wrap the timed call to `executor` in a function; just write `executor` (as Jeff Mercado shows). I'd probably name it "iterator" as that's a bit more descriptive.

6: Minor syntax thing: `typeof` is an operator - not a function - so there's no need to write `typeof(variable)`. In fact the more common way is to write `typeof variable`

7: Another minor syntax thing: You don't have to declare the `executor` as an expression. A straight-up `function executor() { ... }` syntax would work just as well. Of course, since both work it's mostly a matter of personal preference.

Comment: I was also considering making the same change with using the strict comparison but since the return value could have been of differing types, I like seeing specific wording that indicates the type in all the different cases. If it was expected to be of a single type, then yes definitely.

Comment: @JeffMercado The code's identical, though. The wording is just as specific, since the strict comparison literally means "it must be a boolean and it must be false". To be honest, I find the original code less clear, because it's a two-step comparison rather than just saying "if it's _exactly_ false, then..."

Comment: Also might be useful pass current `index` into callback: `index++; var newInterval = callback(collection[index], index);`

Answer (score 3):

My experience with Javascript isn't quite as developed as it is for other languages, but here's what I have to say about the code.

Why use `setInterval()` and `clearInterval()`?  You'd use those methods if you wanted to call a function repeatedly.  Since all you do is set it and immediately clear it, there's no point in really using it.  Better to use `setTimeout()` instead.

I'd consider rearranging your parameters so the `delay` was last.  That way you can make the delay optional, possibly provide a default delay instead.  Also consider making `complatedCallback` optional too.  It could be possible that you don't need the callback so you're forcing yourself to have to provide one.

I don't think you'd want to put a delay of the first invocation on the first item.  So probably should remove that initial timeout and just call the `executor()` directly.

```
DelayedLoop.forEach = function(collection, callback, completedCallback, delay) {
    var index = 0;

    var executor = function() {
        // Executes the callback, and gets the returned value to indicate what the next delay will be.
        var newInterval = callback(collection[index++]);

        // If they returned false, quit looping.
        if (typeof(newInterval) == "boolean" && newInterval == false) {
            return;
        }

        // If nothing / non-number is provided, re-use initial delay.
        if (typeof(newInterval) != "number") {
            newInterval = delay;
        } else if (newInterval < 0) { // If a negative number is returned, quit looping.
            return;
        }

        // If there are more elements to iterate, re-set delayed loop. Otherwise, call the "completed" callback.
        if (index < collection.length) {
            setTimeout(executor, newInterval);
        } else if (typeof(completedCallback) == "function") {
            completedCallback();
        }
    };

    // Initial loop setup.
    executor();
};
```

Otherwise I don't see anything glaringly wrong with the code.